# python: Turning in dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, variables, dataframe

I would like to add dummy variable for the column TypePhase.

```
wm_id                                   TypePhase
   2                   ['N', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
   2                   ['N', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
   3                   ['N', 'W', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
   2                   ['N', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
   3                   ['N', 'P', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
   2                   ['N', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I tried `df.TypePhase = df.TypePhase.apply(lambda s : '_'.join(s))`but I did not get the expected result. I know that  I need the apply

```
pd.get_dummies(df_new['TypePhase']).rename(columns=lambda x: 'AAAAAAAAA_' + str(x))
```

But I don't get it right.
Please, any suggestion?
Many Thanks in advance.
carlo

Comment: I am checking out the provided sol with MultiLabelBinarizer.

Comment: Close but does not solve it completely. it adds " '  ,  F  N  R  S  W  [  ]  a  e  g  h  i  n  o  p  s  t" as list of dummy variable which is wrong.

Comment: I have also tried the other solution, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all values are strings in column `TypePhase`, so is possible use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with double [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html).

Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original.

[`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) function extract column from original, so not necessary delete it.

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'TypePhase']))
<class 'str'>

df1 = df.pop('TypePhase').str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', ')
#remove ' from new column names
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip("'")

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   wm_id  A  B  C  D  N  P  W
0      2  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
1      2  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
2      3  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
3      2  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
4      3  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
5      2  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: yes, it is correct. Problem solved. Many Thanks Jezrael.

Comment: what do you mean with "I think first values are lists"?

Comment: I post link with another answer, because first i think values in column are lists. so it is reason why it does not work

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: just a small one: I am adding a prefix to rename the variable. I am using .rename(columns=lambda x: "AAA_" + str(x)) but I got AAA_'A which has an ' as extra. How Can I avoid it, please?

Comment: maybe need add space like  `df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip("' ")`